# Get MP3 MIME type using python

Tags: python, mp3, mime-types, python-magic

I am writing a script to determine if a file is a valid MP3 using `python-magic`. With some files, the `magic.from_file()` function returns `use count (30) exceeded`. Is it possible to raise the limit similar to the command line program: `file --parameter name=40`? If this is not possible with `python-magic`, is it possible with `filemagic`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After navigating my way through ctypes, I found a solution:

```
import magic

MAGIC_PARAM_NAME_MAX = 1                    # definition from magic.h
name_max = magic.c_void_p(40)               # new use count, can also be c_size_t
name_max_ref = magic.ctypes.byref(name_max)

s = magic.Magic()
magic.libmagic.magic_setparam(s.cookie, MAGIC_PARAM_NAME_MAX, name_max_ref)
print s.from_file('file.jpg')
```

Comment: For some reason this did not work for me. Python exited with a segmentation fault. I am new to python so any help is greatly appreciated. I am using Python 3.x and using the latest magic library from python